# assign material to loaded .obj without .mtl in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

how to add material like THREE.MeshPhongMaterial() to one of objects in loaded .obj file (.obj has multiple objects)

```
        var material_10 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x444444 } );
        var loader = new THREE.OBMLoader();
        loader.load("https://aroncad.com/wp-content/themes/AronCad/3d/satllite/100.obm", function( obj ){
            obj.traverse( function( child ) {

                ...........

            } );
            scene.add( obj );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your issue is the usage of [Object3D.traverse](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.traverse)() like you already do in your code. This approach is also used in the official [OBJ example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj) in order to apply a texture to all materials. The code adapted to your use case looks like so:

```js
object.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child.isMesh ) child.material = material_10;

} );
```

`three.js R109`